# Dismiss a UIPopoverController from another view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPopoverController` named `popover` in another view. What I would like to know is, how can I dismiss the popover if a `UIButton` was pressed in the current popover view? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to tell the other view to dismiss it's popover view.

Example usage:

```
// Add an observer that will respond to our notification.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self // <- This is the object that will has the selector that we want to run (the same one we use in the next line).
                                         selector:@selector(doSomething:) // <- This is the selector we want to run.
                                             name:@"doSomethingNow" // <- This is notification name we will send to activate our observer's selector.
                                           object:nil]; // Don't worry about this for now.


// Post the notification. This has the same name as our observer above, so our 'doSomething' selector should be run.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"doSomethingNow" object:nil];


// the function specified in the same class where we defined the addObserver
- (void)doSomething:(NSNotification *)pNotification {
    NSLog(@"Received Notification..."); 
}
```

Comment: I added some example code. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I always found it odd that a UIViewController knows how big it should be in a popover through it's "contentSizeForViewInPopover" property, but doesn't keep a pointer to the UIPopoverController itself. I always end up adding:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) UIPopoverController* popover;
```

to my UIViewController classes, and set that when creating the popover. Then from anything in that UIViewController, I can do this to dismiss the popover:

```
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```